# How can I deploy an unmanaged DLL with a WPF click-once application?

Tags: wpf, clickonce

I have a WPF click-once application that makes use of an unmanaged dll.

When debugging locally I have just copied the dll into the debug/bin folder.

How can I include the dll in the project (VS2010) so it is deployed and accessible to the application?

I have tried adding it as a Resource and setting "Content" and "Copy Always", and the file does seem to be present in the setup/deployment files, however the application is not able to see it.

If it helps, this is an example of the code I use to access the methods in the unmanaged DLL.

```
 [DllImport("ODBC_VER_DETECT.dll")]
 extern private static long GetCompanyFileVersion([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String sDataBase,
                                                 [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] StringBuilder sVersion);
```

Comment: Can't you simply add the DLL as a content file ?

Comment: yeah - I tried that (see edit)

Comment: My apologies - Rather than going through the whole "Add Resource" rigmarole - I just needed to "Add existing item" into the root folder of the project and then set "Content" and "Copy Always". Thanks Steve B.

Comment: no problem. as you post the answer you found yourself, your a bit helping the community ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rather than going through the whole "Add Resource" rigmarole - I just needed to "Add existing item" into the root folder of the project and then set "Content" and "Copy Always".

Comment: Is there any other, bit more elegant, solution?

Comment: Note:  If the content items are in project A, but project B (dependent on A) is the one you are publishing, then the content files will not be included.  Project B will *not* see the content items from A, so you will not be able to add them as published Application Files.