# (Visual Studio) How to import powershell scripts into c# project so that I can publish my .NET application together with the scripts

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell

I have some custom powershell cmdlets in several scripts, one of which i've loaded an executed as such in C#

```
string Script2 = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\blabla\blabla\ScriptPowershell\TestCheck.ps1");

shell.Commands.Clear();
shell.AddScript(Script2, false);
shell.Invoke();
shell.Commands.Clear();

shell.AddCommand("TestCheck").AddParameter("ServerName", $"{serverId}").AddParameter("ServerPort", $"{serverPort}");

Collection<PSObject> psObjects = shell.Invoke();
```

The main issue with this is that if I publish and install this app on another computer that surely might not have this script at the same exact directory, the cmdlet will not work.

**QUESTION :** Is there a way to publish the app with the scripts joined to it, so that it doesn't need to search in the users computer for the scripts ? Or at least be present in the same directory as the .exe

Any suggestion to solve this problem is welcome.

Thank you !

**Edit 1** : In response to @despacito this is the error message after appyling his solution

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to publish additional files into bin folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52409575/how-to-publish-additional-files-into-bin-folder)

Comment: This seems to be for another reason than the solution I posted. I'd suggest you to make a new question about this error since it's bad practice to have multiple questions on a single post. I'm no expert in this criteria so I unfortunately can't help you here. When you ask this question separately, I would also recommend to open up the "details" tab since it might have valuable information. I wish you good luck!

Comment: Thanks ! I will post another question

Answer (score 1):

You can create a folder within your project to contain your scripts:

[image]

The path must be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, I did that and changed the path to the script when I set the script2 string in the code. When I build the code in VS the script works just fine, but when I publish it and click a button to execute the script it sends an error

Comment: Could you state what the error says?

Btw, to help you with terminology:

**Compiler error**: The thing that checks if the code makes sense before it's run.
**Run time exception**: A mistake that happened during the program was running.

Comment: I updated my question to add the error message that I get @Despacito 2